# How to retrieve id/location of jsonblob-api?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm new to JS and am trying to retrieve the location from [jsonblob/api](https://jsonblob.com/api).

I'm trying to test the example, mentioned in the site. But, was unable to retrieve any location. I've read the doc couple of times but didn't get any reference of the process of getting the location/id of the API call. What should I do?

Here's my code:

```
fetch("https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob", {
            body: '{"people":["bill", "steve", "bob"]}',
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                blobID: "980492826223853568",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            method: "POST"
        }).then(res => {
            console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
        });
```

Although I'm referencing a blobID, but still I don't see any update [here](https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/980492826223853568) after getting status:201. What should I do?

Sorry for my poor English. I'm a non-native speaker.

Comment: Based on the API documentation, the id goes in the URL, not a header.

Comment: @Evert, adding it to the URL gives ERROR 405.

Comment: This suggests that you're trying to use an HTTP method you're not supposed to. What are you trying to do with your request?

Comment: Thanks for revert @Evert. However, I have changed my storage to different bin [npoint](https://www.npoint.io/) for my project and it works like a charm. :)